# how to convert drupal site to html files

Tags: html, drupal-7

I have a site in drupal7 and i want to create offline package.
so - anybody know how to convert the pages in my site to html files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you want a local, static copy of your website ?
you can copy it with tools such as http://www.httrack.com/ . Be aware that any dynamic content will become static, so many features will probably not work.

Comment: I tried the Httrack and really gave us to copy all kinds of other sites except  my site.
My site not famous in the internet, but you can enter it only if you are connected to my server. Could be the problem we are unable to copy it?

Comment: I Found the problem. I just needed to remove the proxy... and now it is work!

Comment: There's a page on drupal.org that also show other methods like wget or site sucker https://www.drupal.org/node/27882

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a backup of the site, I'd suggest you should use the [Backup and Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) module to backup the database and [Backup Migrate Files](http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate_files) module to backup the files.
This would be better to make a backup of your remote site to local system as well.

But, if you require to export the content as HTML pages, you should try the [HTML Export](http://drupal.org/project/html_export) module, which does exactly that.